# Poem about bedtime story for witch's child

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I read this poem in the 5th or 6th grade or so, so that'd be 2012-2014 (somewhere in there). It was out of some packet copied out of a book for this language arts extension thing (I remember the book being very keen on something called "Jacob's ladders" I think, for difficulty of questions or something like it - this was part of a gifted/talented informal class). It was in english but it could very well have been translated. I remember very clearly that it started with lines like

> Tell me a story, said Witch's child 
>   Of the beast so fierce and wild

And ended with a line like

> Something nice to make me sleepy.

I also remember it was reasonably long - it filled up the whole page, which was around 11x13 since it had been copied, in a normal size font with a small illustration at the bottom, I think.

I have no idea how I've remembered it this whole time, so I thought I might actually try to find the poem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

‘Bedtime Stories’ by [Lilian Moore](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poets/lilian-moore) has appeared in many collections, but I think it was originally published in [*See My Lovely Poison Ivy: And Other Verses About Witches, Ghosts and Things*](https://archive.org/details/seemylovelypoiso00moor/page/n11) (1975) with an illustration by Diane Dawson.

[image]

If you’ve seen this poem attributed to a child, that’s because it was plagiarized:

> *Language Arts*, a journal of the National Council of Teachers of English, published in its February, 1983 issue a work by a seventh grader:
>
> > Witch’s Child
> >
> > Tell me a story
> >     Said the witch’s child
> >     […]
> >     So crawly and creepy,
> >     Something nice to make me sleepy.
>
> This is clearly with several word, article, and punctuation changes the work of Lilian Moore, a noted children’s poet.
>
> <sub>Myra Cohn Livingston (1983), [*The child as poet: myth or reality?*](https://archive.org/details/childaspoetmytho00livi/page/146), Boston: The Horn Book, Inc., p.147</sub>

(This is from a long list of examples of published poetry attributed to schoolchildren, that were in fact plagiarized.)

Comment: Actually, I just found the book I read it in, and this is indeed it (Jacob's Ladder Level 2, page 62. Oddly, it cites the poem as being from a fourth or fifth grade student.